# jquery datatable , add extra pagination numbers to load next set of datas via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, pagination

i am using ajax to fetch 50 rows each on jquery datatable. I need to fetch next 50 rows on clicking next page number.
But since its only fetching 50 records at first the page number 1 is only displayed, i need atleast 10 page numbers displayed to click and load the next set of datas.[image]

```
      dashboardTable = $('#dashboard_table').DataTable( {
           "scrollX": true,
           "ordering":true,
           scrollCollapse: true,
           columns: columns,
            "pageLength": 50,
       } );


    function insertRows(){
        var form = $('#form')[0];
        var formData = new FormData(form);
        var url = '/dashboard/dashboard-view';
        $.ajax({
            url:url,
            method:'post',
            data:formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success:function( data){
                    $('.dashboard_table_head').text(data['head']);
                    dashboardTable.rows().remove().draw();
                    dashboardTable.rows.add(data['data']).draw();
            },
            error:function(){
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How about the inbuilt method of [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)? It allows to [set the total number of records](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data) and automatically calculate the number of pages based on `recordsTotal`

Comment: @TomaszKasperczyk   there is many other tables & charts also included in the page. The data of all the charts change according to a drop down through ajax call. So cant  use server side processing.